# Oscillation of the topologist's sine curve and other functions with essential discontinuities.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

The oscillation of a real function $f$ at a point $x_0$ is defined as
$$
\omega_f(x_0) = \limsup_{x\to x_0}f(x) - \liminf_{x\to x_0}f(x).
$$
The Wikipedia page for Oscillation (Mathematics) claims that the topologist's sine curve
$$
T = \left\{\left(x,\sin\frac1x\right):x\in(0,1]\right\}\cup \{(0,0)\}
$$
has oscillation $2$ at point $0$. I apologize for asking multiple questions in one post, but:

1. Why is this the case? I don't see an easy way to compute this quantity.
2. How does this oscillation "measure the failure of a limit to exist"? Does this mean that the greater the oscillation is, the more pathological the limit is?

Comment: Your definition of $\omega_f$ is self-referential, so I cannot make any sense of it.

Comment: Huh, that is a good point. I copied the definition from Wikipedia, but it indeed does not make sense. It also says "This is the same as the difference between the limit superior and limit inferior of the function at $x_0$, provided the point $x_0$ is not excluded from the limits." Does that make more sense as a definition? If so I will edit the post.

Comment: You mean "oscillation $2$ **at $0.$**"

Comment: Verify that $\sin 1/x$ takes on the values $-1,1$ in any neighborhood of $0.$

Comment: @zhw. Oh, that is all there is to it? I have done such an exercise before. The bigger issue now seems to be the definition of oscillation. Should it instead be 
$$
\omega_f(x_0) = \limsup_{x\to x_0}f(x) - \liminf_{x\to x_0}f(x)\quad ?
$$

Comment: Regarding your second question, the oscillation is two times the supremum of all $\varepsilon$ such that the definition of convergence of the limit to $L$ is not satisfied for that $\varepsilon$ no matter what $L$ you pick.

Comment: Or if you don't like the factor of 2 or this introduction of an arbitrary $L$, you can frame it in terms of an analogue of the Cauchy criterion: the oscillation is the supremum of $\varepsilon$ such that (there does not exist $\delta>0$ such that (if $|x-x_0|<\delta,|y-x_0|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon))$. (Here I introduce some parentheses to make the grouping of clauses more clear.)

Answer (score 0):

Solving $\sin\frac1x=1$ for $x$ yields $x = \frac2{4n\pi + \pi}$ and $\sin\frac1x=-1$ for $x$ yields $x=\frac 2{4n\pi+3\pi}$. Hence given any $\varepsilon>0$, we may choose $N$ such that $\min\left\{\frac2{4N\pi + \pi},\frac 2{4N\pi+3\pi}\right\} <\varepsilon$ which shows that $\sin\frac1x$ takes both values $1$ and $-1$ on $(0,\varepsilon)$. It follows that the oscillation of $x\mapsto \sin\frac1x$ at $0$ is
$$
\limsup_{x\to 0}\sin\frac1x - \liminf_{x\to0}\sin\frac1x = 1 - (-1) = 2.
$$